# how to write a sbt file in multiple projects?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to construct a top-level project that is divided into several projects.
The respective projects are not related, and the output of the build I want is the jar files that built each project.

There are a number of ways to build with the sbt command, but all I want is an environment where I can build each project separately, or build all at once.

For example, there are three independent projects, I can use the following virtual command.

```
sbt assembly all -> (output) 3 jars.
sbt assembly project-A -> (output) 1 project-A jar.
sbt assembly project-B -> (output) 1 project-B jar.
sbt assembly project-C -> (output) 1 project-C jar.
```

I would appreciate it if you could write the basics of build.sbt.

In addition, each project can have a dependency on a common library. (For example, a library such as scala-logging)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you create `build.sbt` and declare all of those projects:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
   // task dependency e.g.:
   // root/assembly triggers projectA/assembly and projectB/assembly and projectC/assembly
   // root/test triggers projectA/test and projectB/test and projectC/test
   // etc
  .aggregate(projectA, projectB, projectC)

lazy val projectA = project in file("project-a")

lazy val projectB = project in file("project-b")

lazy val projectC = project in file("project-c")
```

Then, once you add [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#using-published-plugin) to your plugins.sbt you will be able to run `sbt assembly`, which will assembly all of those 3 projects and puts the results in each projects respective `target/scala-[version]/[sth].jar`. Of course e.g. `sbt projectA/assembly` would assembly only projectA, etc.

As for common settings, you can store them in a variable, like:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "my-organization",
  version := "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT",
  libraryDependencies += "organization" %% "library" % "version"
)
```

and then apply it:

```
lazy val projectA = (project in file("project-a"))
   // some project-specific settings
  .settings(
    name := "project-a-module",
    description := "a module of sth sth project"
  )
   // here we take the Seq and use it like vararg
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

One needs some time to grasp it, but sbt allows for plain old Scala in many places. Under the hood `.sbt` files just add some imports (e.g. content of each plugins `autoImport` object) and attach "rouge" settings to (not in any `project.settings()` clause) to current project (so root project for .sbt files in root directory, submodule if .sbt files are in submodule root directory).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: I knew how to write a common build.sbt. Thank you.
I hava a question. 
In addition, do I need each build.sbt file for every project?
Is it possible to specify a common library such as logging in a common build.sbt and specify the libraries needed for each project in each build.sbt?
(Using the keyword "libraryDependencies")